# How can I locally test a gitlab runner script, when the repository uses LFS

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, git-lfs

I am working with GitLab runners and have to test them locally before pushing.

This can be done using

```
gitlab-runner exec docker testing
```

And works well.

Now, if the repository uses LFS, this does not work any longer and I get errors like

```
batch request: missing protocol: "/home/self/workspace/project.git/info/lfs"
```

That seems to be because you cannot just clone a local folder to another one, if LFS is used.

There is a workaround using `git clone --reference` [suggested](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1207)

But how can this be applied to gitlab runner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This crazy hack is working:

```
gitlab-runner exec docker testing --pre-clone-script 'set -x; function git {
  if [[ "$1" == "clone" && "$@" != *"--help"* ]]; then
    command git clone "$2" --reference $3 https://user:password@git.example.com.de/path/to/repo.git "$4" "$5" "$6"   
  else
    command git "$@"
  fi
}'
```

where you have to replace

```
https://user:password@git.example.com.de/path/to/repo.git
```

by the original HTTPs URL of your local repository including username and password.

## What is happening here?

we are redefining the `git clone` command which then executed by the GitLab runner and add the reference option. After successfully cloning, the rest runs as normal.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I tried to replace `https://user:password@git.example.com.de/path/to/repo.git` with my local git repositry and it also worked. That could work even better if you would want to clone with lfs files that were commited locally but not yet pushed to the server.